# Cannot start mongodb network service on Windows 10 after changing dbPath of config file

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

I have installed mongodb 4.2 on my Windows 10 PC. I want to change the `dbPath` from default `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data` to `C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\mongodb_data`.

I modifed mongod.cfg such that
`dbPath: C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\mongodb_data`

When I restart Mongodb network service, I encountered the following error;

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? It might give you a more clear picture. `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log`

Comment: Did you have a look at your log file? Does `xx` include any space character?

Comment: Enclose path by quotes, i.e. `dbPath: "C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\mongodb_data"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running MongoDB with additional parameter `mongod --dbpath <your new path>` it will be reading and writing to this new directory. So, if you want to still have the current documents in Mongo, you can move them to the new directory also.

Comment: It can work but it is different from running mongodb as a network service on Windows 10.